# Handsontable change colors of cells/rows/columns with color picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, renderer, handsontable

I have an example of color change already happening. The issue is that changing the color of a new cell, row, or column will change the color of the previous cell/row/column. The previous cell should keep it's original color, and I need this to happen dynamically with one function (rather than multiple renderers). In the fiddle there are 3 color options, but I'm actually using a color picker with hundreds of options. How can I handle this color change on the fly (right click)?

http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/hkhk5zbo/17/

```
var data = [
        ['', 'Maserati', 'Mazda', 'Mercedes', 'Mini', 'Mitsubishi'],
        ['2009', 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
        ['2010', 3, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
        ['2011', 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
        ['2012', 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151]
    ],
    celldata = [],
    container = document.getElementById('example'),
    hot,
    sentrow,
    sentcol;

var colorRenderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.backgroundColor = $('#color_field').val();

};


var settings = {
    data: data,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    startRows: 5,
    startCols: 5,

    //columns: coldata,
    cell: celldata,
    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
        if (row === sentrow) {
            this.renderer = colorRenderer;
        }
        if (col === sentcol) {
            this.renderer = colorRenderer;
        }
    },
};

hot = new Handsontable(example, settings);

hot.updateSettings({
    contextMenu: {
        callback: function (key, options) {
            if (key === 'cellcolor') {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //timeout is used to make sure the menu collapsed before alert is shown
                    var row = hot.getSelected()[0];
                    var col = hot.getSelected()[1];

                    var item = {};
                    item.row = row;
                    item.col = col;
                    item.renderer = colorRenderer
                    celldata.push(item)

                    hot.updateSettings({cell: celldata});
                    hot.render();

                }, 100);
            }
            if (key === 'rowcolor') {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //timeout is used to make sure the menu collapsed before alert is shown
                    var row = hot.getSelected()[0];
                    sentrow = row;
                    hot.render();

                }, 100);
            }
            if (key === 'colcolor') {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    //timeout is used to make sure the menu collapsed before alert is shown
                    var col = hot.getSelected()[1];
                    sentcol = col;
                    hot.render();

                }, 100);
            }
        },
        items: {
                "cellcolor": {
                name: 'Cell color'
            },
                "rowcolor": {
                name: 'Row color'
            },
                "colcolor": {
                name: 'Column color'
            },
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Refactored the code for clarity.

The color was being changed by subsequent calls because your colorRenderer callback was interrogating the dropdown every time it rendered, rather than capturing the value at the time of the cell style creation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = [
                ['', 'Maserati', 'Mazda', 'Mercedes', 'Mini', 'Mitsubishi'],
                ['2009', 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
                ['2010', 3, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
                ['2011', 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
                ['2012', 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151]
               ];

    var container = document.getElementById('example');

    // Put your color picker function here
    function getSelectedColor() {
        return $('#color_field').val();
    }

    var TableStyles = function(hot) {
        var self = this;

        var _cellStyles = [];

        var _createStyle = function(row, col, color) {
            var _color = color;

            var style = {
                row: row,
                col: col,
                renderer:   function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                                Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                                td.style.backgroundColor = _color;
                            },
                color: function(c) { _color = c; }                
            };       

            return style;
        };

        self.getStyles = function() {
            return _cellStyles;
        };

        self.setCellStyle = function(row, col, color, updateTable) {
            var _color = color;

            if (_cellStyles.length == 0) {
                _cellStyles.push(_createStyle(row, col, color));
            } else {
                var found = _cellStyles.some(function(cell) {
                    if (cell.row == row && cell.col == col) {                        
                        cell.color(color);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                if (!found) {
                    _cellStyles.push(_createStyle(row, col, color));
                }
            }                

            if (updateTable!=false) {
                hot.updateSettings({cell: self.getStyles()});
                hot.render();                        
            };                
        };

        self.setRowStyle = function(row, color) {
            for (var col=0; col<hot.countCols(); col++)
                self.setCellStyle(row, col, color, false);

            hot.updateSettings({cell: self.getStyles()});
            hot.render();                        
        };

        self.setColStyle = function(col, color) {
            for (var row=0; row<hot.countCols(); row++)
                self.setCellStyle(row, col, color, false);

            hot.updateSettings({cell: self.getStyles()});
            hot.render();                        
        };
    };

    var settings = {
        data: data,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        contextMenu: true,
        startRows: 5,
        startCols: 5,
        cell: []
    };

    hot = new Handsontable(container, settings);

    var styles = new TableStyles(hot);        

    hot.updateSettings({
        contextMenu: {
            callback: function (key, options) {                
                if (key === 'cellcolor') {
                    setTimeout(function () {                        
                        var sel = hot.getSelected();                        

                        styles.setCellStyle(sel[0], sel[1], getSelectedColor());
                    }, 100);
                }
                if (key === 'rowcolor') {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        //timeout is used to make sure the menu collapsed before alert is shown
                        var sel = hot.getSelected();                        

                        styles.setRowStyle(sel[0], getSelectedColor());
                    }, 100);
                }
                if (key === 'colcolor') {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        //timeout is used to make sure the menu collapsed before alert is shown
                        var sel = hot.getSelected();                        

                        styles.setColStyle(sel[1], getSelectedColor());
                    }, 100);
                }
            },
            items: {
                    "cellcolor": {
                    name: 'Cell color'
                },
                    "rowcolor": {
                    name: 'Row color'
                },
                    "colcolor": {
                    name: 'Column color'
                },
            }
        }
    })
});
```

The TableStyles object provides a wrapper around the raw cell style array that Handsontable is expecting, so that you cal just call styles.setCellStyle(row, col, color) and it will take care of creating or updating the cell array for you.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McCroskey42/n3eoeqLd/7/)

Comment: This works beautifully, but since I'm using a color picker I'm storing the color outside of the function. http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/0h6yqzw7/23/

Comment: Updated the JSFiddle to reflect that.  You can still capture the value of the selected color in a closure by assigning the value of storedColor to colorValue.

Comment: I've been working on it, and regardless the previous color will change (even though it works in your example perfectly) - super frustrating. It's rather quirky, and i'm not sure. Here's something I'm working on as an alternate (http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/9odsv02x/1/) and the cells work. The rows (on my end) will replace the previous row color and I'm not sure why I have to length - 1 but otherwise it adds an extra column. Maybe it's i <= settings.startCols ?

Comment: Updated again.  There is a single function called getSelectedColor in which you can query the value of whatever color picker you choose to use.

Comment: Do you want the proposed answer to overwrite an existing style if one has already been set, or leave it as is?

Comment: If the user wants to overwrite the chosen cell/row/col yes let's overwrite. Updated with modal, still no luck on my end. http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/n3eoeqLd/10/

Comment: With modal: http://jsfiddle.net/McCroskey42/n3eoeqLd/13 , the code inside the menu was not triggering on modal close.  Moved the style setting into the confirm button's handler, and it works.